# Using transposed DataGrid from DataTable

Tags: c#, datagrid, datatable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#/WPF: Toolkit DataGrid - Transpose rows and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470454/c-wpf-toolkit-datagrid-transpose-rows-and-columns)

I would like to create a DataGridView from a DataTable, composed of internally calculated data, which is the transposed version of the usual dataGrid.

I mean, I would like to have my titles in the first column, each in a row. And would like to add data in new rows.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but it may require some custom code (unfortunately).

Comment: My main doubt is how to make the column titles become row titles.

Comment: Just iterate through DataTable.Column[], grabbing the name as you go. Then add them as the first entry in the applicable row. Again, it takes some custom code, but should work.