# VB.NET DataGridView - All Columns to One Column - Record Row to One Column

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview, combobox, arcgis

**Greetings,**

I have been trying a concept for over 3 hours, and I cannot seem to get it right. I am to the point where I have scrapped all of my code, and I am ready to start off again with some guidance. So, to whomever here can either point me in the right direction, or solve my problem, I would be more than grateful.

**Background:**

I am trying to implement a DataViewGrid in VB.NET that will be simply for identifying and selecting GIS features that are already within a database. Simple enough with DataGrids and DataSets, although there is one slight twist.

**Problem:**

***First***, I need to be able to populate the grid based on one record of the column **[Name]** that is chosen from a ComboBox(I have been able to populate the ComboBox, but not the grid).

***Second,*** I need to restructure the DataGridView so that each current column name is in a column called **"Field"** and the row for that one record chosen is in another column called **"Value".**

---

*For Further Clarification*:

In ArcMap, there is an Identify Tool:

[image]

---

As you can see here, each **"Field"** is a column name and each **"Value"** is one record for each of those columns.

So, if I could somehow parse through all of the column names into a **"Field"** column, and also populate a **"Value"** column with one record for each **[Name],** I would be on the road to happiness.

If there is anything I can do to help you help me, please let me know, and thank you for your time and input in advance.

*Sincerely*,

***Logan***

Answer (score 0):

Transpose your data

Found this question which asks the same thing

[C#/WPF: Toolkit DataGrid - Transpose rows and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470454/c-wpf-toolkit-datagrid-transpose-rows-and-columns)