# DataGrid column bind to a item of the List

Tags: c#, wpf

The ItemsSource of DataGrid is a `List<myClass>`, and `myClass` has a `List<int>` Property.
Now I want to bind the first item of the `List<int>` to the first column of the DataGrid, and the second item to the second column.
How to do it?

XMAL:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyClass Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Item of Numbers" Binding="{Binding ??}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Second Item of Numbers" Binding="{Binding ??}" ></DataGridTextColumn>                                         
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

c#:

```
class MyClass
{            
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public List<int> Numbers= new List<int>();
}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you show some code.

Comment: So you wanted to bind them in columns instead of rows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF horizontal DataGrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132829/wpf-horizontal-datagrid)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the index of the collection.

Example:

```
Text = "{Binding MyClasses[0]}"

Text = "{Binding MyClasses[1]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to transpose rows and columns in datagrid, here are a few answers and resources to refer to.

It's not very straight forward.

- [WPF horizontal DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132829/wpf-horizontal-datagrid)
- [C#/WPF: Toolkit DataGrid - Transpose rows and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470454/c-wpf-toolkit-datagrid-transpose-rows-and-columns)
- https://rotatedwpfdatagrid.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

For a requirement like this, what I would recommend you is --

Our requirement is to have a Collection which has items with properties coming from a list.

For that you can use `Micosoft Dynamics`.. have an ExpandoObject, create properties in the expando object from the List and set the desired cell value there.

So for example your List is { 1, 2, 3, 4 }

We want resultant grid to be

|    1     |    2    |    3    |     4    |

|  value1  |  Value2 |  Value3 |  Value4  |

```
var listOfInt = new List<int>{1,2,3,4};
        var exPo = new ExpandoObject();
        var listOfExPo = new List<ExpandoObject>();

        var expoDict = (IDictionary<string,object>) exPo;

        foreach (var i in listOfInt)
        {
            expoDict.Add(i.ToString(), "value" + i);
        }

        listOfExPo.Add(exPo);
```

Now when you bind your grid to ListOfExpo, you will have a grid with columns coming from ListOfInt

Hope it clears, let me know if you need more info on this.