# Specific Itemsource to datagrid Column - WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, datagrid

I've created a datagrid, which will create a column whenever a user decides to, with that in mind what should I bind the column to ?

I've tried creating a class :

```
 public class Column
    {
        public List<List<string>> DataList { get; set; }

        public Column()
        {
            DataList = new List<List<string>>();
        }
    }
```

and binding the column like so :

```
    DataGridTextColumn item = new DataGridTextColumn
    {
        Header = "Index1",
        Width = 200,
        Binding = new Binding("DataList[0]") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay }
    };
```

but it seems to not work.

I'm sorry if this question is common, and if so I apologize, but I've tried googling it and can't get it to work.

Comment: what does your `DataGrid look like aspx markup` are these Bound Fields

Comment: The whole program is in WPF, with the Mahapps package.

Comment: It looks like similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851800/datagrid-column-bind-to-a-item-of-the-list